# Cannot connect to AWS RHEL Instance using SSH from windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I created an AWS RHEL instance but cannot connect to it using ssh from Windows using

`c:\Users\simon\Downloads>ssh -i "Mega3.pem" ec2-user@ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

I get

`ec2-user@ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

I am launching ssh from the downloads directory which contains the key file created when I created the instance. The permission has been changed to provide full control access to my account only.

I added a security group rule to allow pinging the server as below
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The verbose log from ssh is below

````
  OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
  debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
  debug1: Connecting to ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com [13.210.225.73] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file Mega3.pem type -1
  debug1: identity file Mega3.pem-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
  debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug1: Authenticating to ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\simon/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
  debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:vDtm+N1kYnIhhqQ61Rj8d5UKT2IoVbFSir7B4IDaDUM
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\simon/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
  debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
  debug1: Host 'ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
  debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\simon/.ssh/known_hosts:6
  debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
  debug1: Will attempt key: Mega3.pem  explicit
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
  debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: Mega3.pem
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  ec2-user@ec2-13-210-225-73.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).```




[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1tyb.png
````

Comment: try changing permission on pem file. chmod 400 "Mega3.pem"

Comment: chmod is not a windows command

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jaskiratr/cfacb332bfdff2f63f535db7efb6df93 this is equivalent to windows. mostly looks like permission issue with pem file.

Comment: permissions are the same as on another key file with which I successfully connected to an AWS RHEL instance. I don't think pem file permissions are the issue

Comment: Maybe the key file is simply wrong.

Comment: Have you renamed the key file?

Comment: Key file has not been renamed

Comment: Are you able to connect to the instance using `Connect to instance` on the instance summary page?

Comment: No. Error message EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see Set up EC2 Instance Connect at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html.

Comment: I have done all the things suggested in the User Guide for Linux Instances and I still can't connect

Comment: At least we know it is a problem with the instance. I am guessing it is a problem with the SSH version installed with your AMI. Maybe the openssh got updated there and is not supporting the TLS version of the key and / or client. I've seen this before.

Comment: Created a new instance with same properties and can connect to it OK